# Deep-reverse of nested lists in Scala

Tags: list, scala, recursion

I'd like to reverse a list of lists, recursively, in Scala.

I've written deep list reverses in Python like this:

```
def deepReverse(items):
    if type(items) == list:
        return [deepReverse(item) for item in reversed(items)]
    else: 
        return items
```

How would I do the equivalent in Scala? The problem isn't the algorithm - it's the type stuff, which I'm newer on.

I need the function to take a list of [T], or a List[List[T]], or a list of T's and lists of Ts, to any arbitrary depth. I tried making a case class to do that based on an example I'd seen elsewhere. I don't want a function that just returns Any and accepts Any; that feels like cheating.

```
case class NL[+T](val v : Either[List[NL[T]],T])
```

Still, I couldn't quite get my types to balance out. I'm new to Scala, but I figured it'd be a perfect opportunity to mess with recursion and typing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's actually not too hard to write a version of the type class approach that sschaef proposes that will work for arbitrarily nested lists:

```
trait Reverser[C] {
  def reverse(xs: C): C
}

implicit def rev[A](implicit ev: Reverser[A] = null) = new Reverser[List[A]] {
  def reverse(xs: List[A]) =
    Option(ev).map(r => xs map r.reverse).getOrElse(xs).reverse
}

def deepReverse[A](xs: A)(implicit ev: Reverser[A]): A = ev.reverse(xs)
```

The implicit argument `ev` in our `rev` method is evidence that `A` itself is reversable, and if `ev` is null that means it's not. If we have this evidence that `A` is reversable, we use it to reverse the elements of our `List[A]` (this is what the `map` is doing), and then we reverse the list itself. If we don't have this evidence (the `getOrElse` case), we can just reverse the list.

We could write `rev` a little less concisely (but possibly more performantly) like this:

```
implicit def rev[A](implicit ev: Reverser[A] = null) = if (ev == null) {
  new Reverser[List[A]] {
    def reverse(xs: List[A]) = xs.reverse
  }
} else {
  new Reverser[List[A]] {
   def reverse(xs: List[A]) = (xs map ev.reverse).reverse
  }
}
```

To test either of these two versions, we can write the following:

```
scala> deepReverse(List.tabulate(3)(identity))
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 0)

scala> deepReverse(List.tabulate(2,3) { case (a, b) => a + b })
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(3, 2, 1), List(2, 1, 0))

scala> deepReverse(List.tabulate(2, 3, 4, 5, 6) {
     |   case (a, b, c, d, e) => a + b + c + d + e
     | }).head.head.head.head
res2: List[Int] = List(15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10)
```

As expected.

---

I should add that the following is a more common idiom for getting the implicits right in a case like this:

```
trait ReverserLow {
  implicit def listReverser[A] = new Reverser[List[A]] {
    def reverse(xs: List[A]) = xs.reverse
  }
}

object ReverserHigh extends ReverserLow {
  implicit def nestedListReverser[A](implicit ev: Reverser[A]) =
    new Reverser[List[A]] {
      def reverse(xs: List[A]) = xs.map(ev.reverse).reverse
    }
}

import ReverserHigh._
```

If we'd just written `listReverser` and `nestedListReverser` at the same level, we'd get the following error when we try to reverse a list of lists:

```
scala> deepReverse(List.tabulate(2, 3)(_ + _))
<console>:12: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both method listReverser...
 and method nestedListReverser...
 match expected type Reverser[List[List[Int]]]
              deepReverse(List.tabulate(2, 3)(_ + _))
```

The standard approach to prioritizing the two is to put the lower priority implicit in a trait (`WhateverLow`) and the other in an object (`WhateverHigh`) that extends that trait. In a fairly simple case like this, though, it's more concise (and clearer, to my eye) to use the default argument trick in my `rev` method above. But you're more likely to see the other version in other people's code.

Comment: Damn! I didn't thought of injecting the typeclass to itself. Great trick!

Comment: That's fantastic! So, the getOrElse returns the value itself if there's no map returned? Much appreciated.

Comment: @GrittyKitty: Thanks! See my update for more of an explanation of the trick here.

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna have this really typesafe then the typeclass pattern is your friend:

```
object Reverse extends App {

  trait Reverser[C] {
    def reverse(xs: C): C
  }

  implicit def List1Reverser[A] = new Reverser[List[A]] {
    def reverse(xs: List[A]) =
      xs.reverse
  }

  implicit def List2Reverser[A] = new Reverser[List[List[A]]] {
    def reverse(xs: List[List[A]]) =
      xs.map(_.reverse).reverse
  }

  implicit def List3Reverser[A] = new Reverser[List[List[List[A]]]] {
    def reverse(xs: List[List[List[A]]]) =
      xs.map(_.map(_.reverse).reverse).reverse
  }

  def deepReverse[A](xs: A)(implicit rev: Reverser[A]): A =
    rev.reverse(xs)

  val xs = List(1,2)
  val xxs = List(List(1,2),List(1,2),List(1,2))
  val xxxs = List(List(List(1,2),List(1,2)),List(List(1,2),List(1,2)),List(List(1,2),List(1,2)))

  println(deepReverse(xs))
  println(deepReverse(xxs))
  println(deepReverse(xxxs))
}
```

The only problem with this is that you need a typeclass for each nested list type.

Comment: Much appreciated, though I'm definitely looking for nesting to arbitrary depths, which means I can't really go define a new reverser for every level.

Comment: Are you sure you will have "really" arbitrary depths? I mean is a level of 10 (for example) not enough?

Comment: +1 but arbitrary depth is possible (I'd have posted my answer in a comment here if it would have fit).

Comment: @sschaef: It's an issue of curiosity, completely divorced from practicality. Thanks a bunch :-)