# How to be able to apply implict conversions in a recursive way in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, implicits

I am trying to write a conversions library for converting some scala types to an HTML representation. I would want, say, to execute `List(1,2).toHtml` and obtain `<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>`, as a `String`.
So far i've written a set of implicit conversions that work well on detecting the result type and applying the correct `toHtml`.

Let me show a sample:

```
object Conversions {

  implicit def fromIterable[A](l : Iterable[A]) = new Object {
       def toHtml = <ul> { l.map{ e => <li>{ e }</li> } } </ul> toString
  }
}
import Conversions._
```

With this code, whenever i ask the compiler `List(1,2).toHtml` i get the correct conversion. As it would with any other `Iterable` val.

My problem and question here is how can i use this toHtml conversion recursively? Because if i typed `List( List(1,2), List(3,4) ).toHtml` i would want to get `<ul> <li><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></li> <li><ul><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul></li> </ul>`, the `toHtml` conversion applied recursively to every element of the input `Iterable`.

I tried to change the `toHtml` definition to `def toHtml = <ul> { l.map{ e => <li>{ e.toHtml  }</li> } } </ul> toString` which didn't work because the compiler told me `value toHtml is not a member of type parameter A` which makes perfect sense.
I know that my problem probably resides in the `new Object { ... }` i am returning from the `fromIterable[A]` implicit definition, which should probably be returning a class with a trait or something.
I've tried reading a lot about implicits but i haven't figured it out yet out to be able to apply recursively this `toHtml` conversion without de-parametizing the fromIterable signature and defining several specific cases like `fromIterable(l : List[List[Any]])` or something like that...

Can you guys please me give me some advices on how to achieve it and what am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can solve this kind of problem in an elegant and type-safe way with [type classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class):

```
// Evidence that we can turn an A into some XML:
trait Markup[-A] { def toHtml(a: A): xml.Node }

def baseMarkup[A] = new Markup[A] { def toHtml(a: A) = xml.Text(a.toString) }

implicit def markup[A](implicit m: Markup[A] = baseMarkup[A]) =
  new Markup[Iterable[A]] {
    def toHtml(c: Iterable[A]) = <ul>
      { c.map(child => <li>{ m.toHtml(child) }</li>) }
    </ul>
  }

implicit def fromMarkup[A](a: A)(implicit m: Markup[A]) = new {
  def toHtml = m toHtml a
}
```

This works for nested lists of arbitrary depth:

```
val messy = List(List(List("a")), List(List("b", "c"), List("c")))

val printer = new xml.PrettyPrinter(80, 2)
```

And then:

```
scala> printer format messy.toHtml
res1: String = 
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>a</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>b</li>
          <li>c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>c</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648663/334519) for a more detailed explanation of the methods above.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution seems more elegant and close to what i thought i had to do. Which was using a trait to define that a certain type would have a toHtml method so that i could apply it. However, as i tried your code, i couldn't figure out how to apply this to Iterables instead of only Lists... Any hints?

Comment: Make the type parameter of `Markup` contravariant and change `List` to `Iterable` in the `markup` method and you're all set. I'll update the answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks to Miles Sabin for [pointing out a way](https://twitter.com/milessabin/status/275599745328766976) this can be simplified a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: Travis Brown, this solution is great and i think i have here almost everything i need to create a solution on which i could apply conversions recursively to any type. I'm trying to do it for Maps where i'm creating an HTML table. However, as i'm not still very experienced with Scala i am not getting the hang of it... Do i need an additional trait like Markup[A,B] ? I'm sorry to bother you with such specific needs but i'm trying everything to fully understand these concepts.

Comment: You can write something like an `implicit def mapMarkup[A: Markup, B: Markup]: Markup[Map[A, B]]`, but you'll need a trait and object to prioritize the implicits (so that the map doesn't just get treated as an iterable). I'll try to update the answer tonight.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first see how we can do it without the whole implicit/object and conversions stuff. I also removed the `toString` but feel free to add it on call.

```
def toHtml[A](l:Iterable[A]):scala.xml.Elem  = 
  <ul> {l.map( _ match{ 
    case e:Iterable[_] => <li>{toHtml(e)}</li> 
    case e => <li>{e}</li>
  })}</ul>

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

toHtml: [A](l: Iterable[A])scala.xml.Elem
scala> toHtml(List(List(1,2), List(3,4)))
res17: scala.xml.Elem = <ul> <li><ul> <li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></li><li><ul> <li>3</li><li>4</li></ul></li></ul>
```

Let us now re-wrap everything in order to answer your question:

```
object Conversions {
  implicit def fromIterable[A](l : Iterable[A]):Object{def toHtml:xml.Elem} = new Object {
    def toHtml:xml.Elem  = 
      <ul>{l.map( _ match{ 
        case e:Iterable[_] => <li>{e.toHtml}</li> 
        case e => <li>{e}</li>
      })}</ul>
  }
}
import Conversions._
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
scala> List(List(1,2), List(3,4)).toHtml
res3: scala.xml.Elem = <ul><li><ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul></li><li><ul><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul></li></ul>
```

A few remarks:

- Second, I had to give the return type of the 'fromIterable' method. I am sure that there exists a better solution but I am not that experienced with implicit conversions.
- Finally, I will be glad to edit my answer if anyone has suggestions. (Or feel free to edit)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, i think it's what i was looking for! I'm still not totally sure but as i will integrate this on my work i will let you know.

Comment: As for the warning you got, you can simply remove the B from the signature and instead write `case e:Iterable[_] => ...` and it works.