# Scala 2.10.2: How to dynamically load class from string?

Tags: scala, dynamic-programming, scala-2.10

I have some statically compiled trait:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def printMessage()
}
```

And I have some string:

```
val a = """class SomeClass extends SomeTrait{override def printMessage() = {println("hello")}}"""
```

How can I dynamically load class from file?

Something like this, for example:

```
var b : SomeTrait = ClassLoader[SomeTrait](a)
b.pringMessage()
```

I saw some class like `Interpreter` in previous versions of Scala, but didn't find it in Scala 2.10.2. I newbie in Scala, so I may wrong.

Comment: From what  I've understood: you want an eval function in Scala. You can take a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183645/eval-in-scala) from 2009 about it.

Comment: For testing purposes I used this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15323481/596816

Comment: You want to use the recent support for reflection/using the compiler, and @EECOLOR is using exactly that API. This API did not exist in 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to check [twitter-util eval](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala).