# Testing Scala compile-time behavior with sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Testing runtime behavior is very well documented but with the advent of powerful type systems and macro system one might be interested in testing compile-time behavior.

For instance when writing a library that provides compile-time guarantees. Say I'm building a set of test matchers and I want to make sure a matcher is as type-safe as I claim it to be.

```
List(1,2) must beEqualTo(Set(1,2)) // should fail at compile-time
```

I can see in the scala compiler project that most of the tests are functional tests where the compiler output is asserted by comparing it with a reference file.
Is there a convention for such tests? An SBT plugin?

Thanks

Comment: The canonical Q&A is http://stackoverflow.com/q/15125457/1296806 where partest gets a mention but the consensus is that a macro that runs the type check is the best solution. Note that there is a subtle difference between type checking and surviving to the end of compilation.

Comment: Very good! I looked for something like that but couldn't find it... Thanks!