# How do I write a scala unit test that ensures compliation fails?

Tags: unit-testing, scala

Is there any way to write something like a "unit test" which makes sure some code does *not* compile?

Why would I want such a thing?  Two reasons.

1) Check the type safety of my API.  I'd like a way to make sure if someone passes in a bad value, you get a compiler error, not just a runtime error.  Obviously, I can just run the compiler and check for the error, but having it formalized in a unit test is good for avoiding a regression & also for documentation.

Eg., consider this test.  There is some commented out code which I had used to check type-safety:
https://github.com/squito/boxwood/blob/master/core/src/test/scala/com/quantifind/boxwood/EnumUnionTest.scala#L42
(lines 42 & 48 -- on line 34 I call a different API which has a runtime exception, which I can check)

It actually took me a while to get the type-safety right, so those were important checks.  Now if I go and modify the underlying implementation, I can't just run my test suite -- I've got to also remember to uncomment those lines and check for a compiler error.

2) Testing error handling of macros.  If a macro has some bad input, it should result in a compiler error.  Same issues here, same desire to have it in a easy-to-run test-suite.

I use ScalaTest, but I'm happy to here a solution with any unit-testing framework.

Comment: The obvious solution to that is to write a unit test that runs the compiler on a resource that is specified in that unit test and to parse the output of the compile. Viewing it in this kind of way the source code isn't the unit test itself, but just a resource to run a unit test.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Testing an assertion that something must not compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125457/testing-an-assertion-that-something-must-not-compile)

Comment: See [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15125457/334519), [Miles Sabin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15132961/334519), and the new [`illTyped` macro in Shapeless 2.0](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/49ef0311cadb648653c3749ae057127fe1f265d6/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/test/typechecking.scala).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I note in a comment above, [Shapeless 2.0](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) (not yet released but currently available as a milestone) has a very nice implementation of the functionality you're looking for, based on a solution by Stefan Zeiger. I've added a demo to your project [here](https://github.com/travisbrown/boxwood) (note that I've had to update to Scala 2.10, since this solution uses a macro). It works like this:

```
import shapeless.test.illTyped

//this version won't even compile
illTyped("getIdx(C.Ooga)")

//We can have multiple enum unions exist side by side
import Union_B_C._
B.values().foreach {b => Union_B_C.getIdx(b) should be (b.ordinal())}
C.values().foreach {c => Union_B_C.getIdx(c) should be (c.ordinal() + 2)}

//Though A exists in some union type, Union_B_C still doesn't know about it,
// so this won't compile
illTyped("""
  A.values().foreach {a => Union_B_C.getIdx(a) should be (a.ordinal())}
""")
```

If we were to change the code in the second call to `illTyped` to something that will compile:

```
B.values().foreach {a => Union_B_C.getIdx(a) should be (a.ordinal())}
```

We'd get the following compilation error:

```
[error] .../EnumUnionTest.scala:56: Type-checking succeeded unexpectedly.
[error] Expected some error.
[error]     illTyped("""
[error]             ^
[error] one error found
[error] (core/test:compile) Compilation failed
```

If you'd prefer a failed test, you could pretty easily adapt [the implementation in Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/test/typechecking.scala). See [Miles's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15132961/334519) to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15125457/334519) for some addition discussion.

Comment: Thanks Travis, sorry for the duplicate question.  You went above & beyond by modifying my code for me!  Also, see my answer below, about problems using it in the repl, curious if you have any thoughts on that.

Answer (score 9):

Scalatest can also do this.

[Checking that a snippet of code does not compile](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingThatCodeDoesNotCompile)

> Often when creating libraries you may wish to ensure that certain
>   arrangements of code that represent potential “user errors” do not
>   compile, so that your library is more error resistant. ScalaTest
>   Matchers trait includes the following syntax for that purpose:
>
> ```
> "val a: String = 1" shouldNot compile
> ```
>
> If you want to ensure that a
>   snippet of code does not compile because of a type error (as opposed
>   to a syntax error), use:
>
> ```
> "val a: String = 1" shouldNot typeCheck
> ```
>
> Note that the `shouldNot typeCheck` syntax will only succeed if the given snippet of code does
>   not compile because of a type error. A syntax error will still result
>   on a thrown `TestFailedException`.
>
> If you want to state that a snippet of code does compile, you can make
>   that more obvious with:
>
> ```
> "val a: Int = 1" should compile
> ```
>
> Although the previous three constructs
>   are implemented with macros that determine at compile time whether the
>   snippet of code represented by the string does or does not compile,
>   errors are reported as test failures at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Travis Brown's answer is absolutely correct.  Just in the interest of completeness, I want to add that this also works for testing macros, as demonstrated [here](https://github.com/squito/learn_macros/commit/8c64853e2d09d7e4203ec2356bbb3769860ef082).

One minor point: the `illTyped` check doesn't seem to work in the repl.  It never throws an error, even if the given expression *does* type check.  But don't let that fool you, it does work well.

```
> test:console
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def foo(s: String) = s
foo: (s: String)String

scala> import shapeless.test.illTyped
import shapeless.test.illTyped

scala> foo(1)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              foo(1)
                  ^

scala> illTyped("""foo(1)""")

scala> illTyped("""foo("hi there")""")  // <--- works, but shouldn't!
```

Comment: The problem is that in the REPL the context that the code is being type-checked in isn't necessarily what you'd expect. `illTyped("2 + 2")` will fail as expected, as will well-typed code using any available classes defined outside of the REPL. The macro context doesn't see the definition of `foo`, though, so it considers `foo("hi there")` ill-typed and lets it past. I admit this is confusing, but it's entirely a REPL issue.