# Scala path-dependent type: testing for type error

Tags: scala, scalatest, path-dependent-type

I've written some Scala to work with modular arithmetic using path dependent types. The parent class represents a group modulo some integer, and the inner class represents elements of this group.

```
class ModularInt( modulus : Int ) {
  case class Value( value: Int ) {
    def plus( a: Value ) : Value = {
      val rem: Int = (value + a.toInt) % modulus
      if( rem < 0 )
        Value(modulus + rem)
      else
        Value(rem)
    }

    def toInt = value
  }
}
```

This seems to work correctly (e.g. modulo 7: 6 + 2 = 1).

A nice side effect of using path-dependent types is that numbers modulo different integers will throw a type error if you try to operate them together. However, I would like to insert a test that will confirm this fact.

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ModularIntSuite extends FunSuite {
  test("a mod n + b mod m => error") {
    val n: Int = 3
    val m: Int = 4
    val modulen = new ModularInt( n )
    val modulem = new ModularInt( m )

    val a = new modulen.Value(0)
    val b = new modulem.Value(0)

    assert(a plus b) // catch error here
  }
}
```

However, as `a plus b` throws a type error at compile time, the test won't even run.

Is there anyway to insert a test for a compile error? Or does the fact that compile errors are tests of correctness themselves mean that this is a redundant check (i.e. what I'm trying to do makes no sense)?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114298/how-do-i-write-a-scala-unit-test-that-ensures-compliation-fails

Answer (score 0):

The test is redundant. One of the advantages of a strong type system is precisely this, that if you design your types correctly the code won't even compile.

Comment: Not at all ... particularly when working with type classes it can be important to know that instances are _not_ available for specific types. In that case you need to verify that relevant expression do not in fact compile.

Comment: @MilesSabin I stand corrected. Thanks!