# Is it possible to assert compilation error in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, assert

For example in Scala one can do following (ScalaTest):

```
assertDoesNotCompile("val a: String = 1")
assertTypeError("val a: String = 1")
assertCompiles("val a: Int = 1")
```

Does something similar exist in TypeScript world?

Edit:
I mean context-aware compilation. For example code from this question [How do I write a scala unit test that ensures compliation fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114298/how-do-i-write-a-scala-unit-test-that-ensures-compliation-fails):

```
import shapeless.test.illTyped

//this version won't even compile
illTyped("getIdx(C.Ooga)")

//We can have multiple enum unions exist side by side
import Union_B_C._
B.values().foreach {b => Union_B_C.getIdx(b) should be (b.ordinal())}
C.values().foreach {c => Union_B_C.getIdx(c) should be (c.ordinal() + 2)}

//Though A exists in some union type, Union_B_C still doesn't know about it,
// so this won't compile
illTyped("""
  A.values().foreach {a => Union_B_C.getIdx(a) should be (a.ordinal())}
""")
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a feature of Scala, it's a feature of ScalaTest which uses scala compiler at runtime as a library.

You can use typescript compiler as a library, it has rather complicated API documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).

I have a node module [published on github](https://github.com/fictitious/tsc-simple) that simplifies things a bit, you can use it like this:

```
import {createCompiler, CompileResult} from 'tsc-simple';

const compiler= createCompiler({defaultLibLocation:'node_modules/typescript/lib'});

const r: CompileResult = compiler.compile('let x = 3 + 2');

assert.lengthOf(r.diagnostics, 0);
```

(using assert from [chai module](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/))

Comment: I think Scala has some way with types to crash when the compiler resolves them. But yes, this case is not a Scala feature directly, Scala only allows to use compiler. Your library with few helper functions could do the same thing as ScalaTest. Thank you for answering :).

Comment: It occurred to me that your solution probably will work only without context, that's not what I meant. I'll update the question.

Comment: Then the answer is definitely no, nothing like scala macros exists in typescript.

Comment: @monnef it seems to me that this answer deserves an upvote. It seems that (at least for some situations) it is possible to assert compilation error using tsc-simple lib that artem shared

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly your use case, but TypeScript 3.9 has the `// @ts-expect-error` comment which may be useful for people:

```
const x = 5;
// @ts-expect-error
const y: string = x;
```

Note that this comment will let you *break things* if you are not careful, so e.g. you should not use `y` in the example above even though the compiler will let you.