# Is it possible to throw a custom error for tsc compilation in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to throw a custom error for tsc compilation time, not for runtime, if a certain condition is met.

The reason I want to do this is to prevent passing arguments of certain combination.

E.g.

```js
f("A", "C"); // ok
f("A", "D"); // ok
f("B", "C"); // ok
f("B", "D"); // no, wanna prevent this combination of arguments
```

In the function, I want something like this:

```js
function f(arg1: "A" | "B", arg2: "C" | "D") {
  if (arg1 === "B" && arg2 === "D") {
    // wanna throw a TS custom error here
  }

  // do some tasks...
}
```

A similar question have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44498861/13651701), but answers doesn't provide a way to accomplish this with native TS features.

Is there no TS feature to do what I want?

---

Old E.g. before edit

```js
function root(radical: number, radicand: number) {
  // even root of a negative number does not exist
  if (radical % 2 === 0 && radicand < 0) {
    // wanna throw a TS custom error here
  }

  // do some calculation here
  ...

  return answer;
}
```

Comment: There are no "custom" compilation error (there's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#23689](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689) for it).  But even if there were, I don't understand what you're asking for.  You want the compiler to warn unconditionally in that block? Like, [this](//tsplay.devWkjqpm)?  That doesn't make much sense. Do you want the compiler to *predict* whether or not something like `root(2, -25)` will be called and only *then* issue an error *in that block*? It can't predict runtime. Help me out here.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your comments and links. [This link](https://tsplay.devwkjqpm/) seems not working but the GitHub issue is informative. I have updated my example to make it clear, though as you said "It can't predict runtime.", I thought maybe it's the limitation or something I shouldn't want TS to do? I hope there was some workaround.

Comment: Sorry that link should have looked like [this](//tsplay.dev/NDG0Rw).  If you want to prevent a function from being callable in a certain way, you need to make its call signature(s) preclude that way of calling it, and it has nothing to do with the implementation.  With your new example you can do something like [this](//tsplay.dev/m0Ldnm); does that meet your needs? Note you have no chance of detecting even or negative numbers at compile time, because such types cannot be represented (see maybe [ms/TS#43505](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43505) for the feature request)

Comment: @jcalz That's indeed what I want! But the part of code constructing the custom type seems a bit difficult to me. I guess I have to learn TypeScript more. Anyway, at least knowing TypeScript is capable of this is very motivating. Thank you for sharing the cool code.